# How to get $_GET variable in the event listener of symfony

Tags: php, docker, symfony, event-listener

I'm using docker, php 8.2, symfony 6.2. The protocol is HTTP.
I have a very simple event listener of symfony, which listen request

```php
<?php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class LocaleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/test.txt', print_r($request->query->all(), true));
        return;
        
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => [['onKernelRequest', 1000]],
        ];
    }
}
```

The issue is `$request->query->all()` return empty array as well as $_GET. But query string is not empty. How to get $_GET variable in the event listener of symfony?

Comment: maybe another subscriber call `$request->query->clear()` for some reason, i guess because of security, to force you to use that instead raw input. you could try to run your code in empty project to test that idea.

Comment: Does the debug toolbar show variable for your request?  Perhaps a malformed url?  Your code seems right.

Comment: I investigated the code and it turned out that this subscriber is called twice. The second call is from symfony debugger. Debugger doesn't send any query parameters that why $request->query is empty.